# Loop through query results and run another query for each result using QueryChainer

Tags: javascript, database, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble looping through a results set and then running another query for each result in order to attach some additional data.

I looked around on the Github issues for Sequelize.js and found that it's possible to [use QueryChainer to achieve this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/838#issuecomment-22777972). However, since I'm still a novice at this, I havent been able to figure out how to do so. Execution of my `for` loop happens asynchronously, resulting in a response being sent without the additional data.

Here's how I'm doing it right now:

```
// in blogs.js
var db = require('../models')

exports.findPosts = function(req, res) {

  if (req.User) {

    req.User.getPosts({
      include: [
        { model: db.User, attributes: ['displayName', 'profilePicture'] },
        { model: db.Game, attributes: ['name'] }
      ]
    }).success(function(posts) {

      console.log('Starting the loop...')

      for (var i in posts) {

        db.PostLikes.count({ where: { PostId: i.id } }).success(function(likes) {

          i.Likes = likes
          console.log('Fetched Likes for post #' + i.id)

        })

      }

      console.log('This should appear last!')
      res.json(posts)

    }).error(function(err) {

      console.log(err)
      res.send(404)

    })

  } else {
    res.send(404)
  }
}
```

The above code results in the response being sent without the `Likes` attribute appended to each `post` item. The `console.log`s appear out of order due to the nature of asynchronicity of the `db.PostLikes.count()` call.

It would be immensely helpful if someone could show me a way to use QueryChainer to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To whoever's looking for a solution for this issue:

I resolved it by help from one of the maintainers of SequelizeJS over [on Github](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/838). A part of my solution was to use the 'bluebird' library for Promises. It might be possible to use a different library, but I haven't tested my code with any other yet.

[Here's a Gist of my code.](https://gist.github.com/jagged3dge/1ae038cf050662986121) I hope this helps anyone running into this issue :)